# Is there a compelling reason to upgrade to MVC5, having gone from MVC3 to MVC4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-5.1

I have an MVC3 in production, running on ASP.NET 4.5, EF6.1, C#.

I have now upgraded it to MVC4 on QA.

I am not developing it significantly, just tweaks to performance. So the 2 features that interested me were:

```
a) Greater use of Async behaviour to improve scalability
b) Improved View rendering performance through newer versions of Razor
```

However the main bottleneck is interaction with the database which is unrelated to MVC5 or MVC4 for that matter.

The rewrite of the application will likely be in ASP.NET5/VNext which is totally different anyway. So I am really wondering whether there is any point in upgrading to MVC5, as its new features are things that our application do not use apart from Razor3 I guess.

Thoughts appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Working with newer technologies are always awesome
Mvc5 has add this new

> Attribute Routing [Route("Controller/{ID}")]

```
   [Route("Controller/{Id}")]
    public ActionResult GetBYID( int Id)
    {
        //TODO: Put your logic here.       
        return View();
```

}

> ASP.NET Identity which is super awesome for social networks

we used this for our Campus project :)

MVC5 is your choice